# Why is ccrewrite.exe not doing anything from the command line?

Tags: .net-4.0, code-contracts, ccrewrite

I've got Code Contracts working fine from inside Visual Studio 2010, but I can't get `ccrewrite.exe` to do anything useful from the command line. Here's a sample app:

```
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;

public class Dummy
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Contract.Requires(args.Length > 0);
    }
}
```

I then compile the code and run ccrewrite.exe on it:

```
> csc /debug+ /D:CONTRACTS_FULL Dummy.cs

> ccrewrite /o:RewrittenDummy.exe Dummy.exe
elapsed time: 61ms
```

There's no `RewrittenDummy.exe` file afterwards.

I've tried loads of options, but nothing's making any difference. A few things I've noticed:

- It's definitely loading Dummy.exe, because if I specify a non-existent file, it dies
- Dummy.exe definitely contains references to Contract - if I run it with no arguments, it fails appropriately (but the error message hasn't been filled in as I'd expect if it had been rewritten)
- Using postconditions and invariants makes no difference

I've tried turning warnings and verbosity up, and that doesn't help at all
What am I doing wrong?

(Also asked as a [question in the Code Contracts forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/codecontracts/thread/0cf6ce81-4778-4ec5-adfe-c12c9da23c7e). I'll add any relevant answers here myself.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Okay, this has been [answered in the MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/codecontracts/thread/0cf6ce81-4778-4ec5-adfe-c12c9da23c7e). For once, it wasn't really me being entirely stupid - it's something that could really do with a warning.

Read the forum post for full details, but the basic problem is that `ccrewrite` couldn't find the contract classes: it was looking in the .NET 3.5 CLR version of `mscorlib` instead of the .NET 4.0 one.

This can be fixed by explicitly listing the path to the relevant assembly:

```
> ccrewrite /o:rewrittendummy.exe dummy.exe 
  /libpaths:%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.20506
```

Comment: Where I add this line?

Comment: Ive commented all my Contracts call and returned to the old and good != null... ccrewrite  is too buggy.

Comment: @Pedro77: It's hard to tell exactly what your problem is from these comments. Perhaps open a new question?

Comment: Oh, never mind. My doubt here is where should I write your solution: " > ccrewrite /o:rewrit..." ?? Can you please clarify?

Comment: @Pedro77: Well that's if you're running it from the command line. If you're just using Visual Studio, you'll need to work out which project options correspond to which command-line options.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Isn't there a simple way to set up code contracts to throw a plain old CLR exception when `Contract.Requires<NullReferenceException>(obj != null);`?

Comment: @Shimmy: It will do that already, won't it? (So long as the rewriter is set to check everything.) I'm not quite sure what you're asking - but it's been a long time since I've used CC anyway.

Comment: @JonSkeet looks like it doesn't. I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC project and I get complains about ccwriter.

Comment: @Shimmy: Sounds like you should ask a new question with plenty of detail.