# Using Code Contracts in library code built with MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, code-contracts, ccrewrite

I've started using [Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx) in all new code I'm writing, such as in a framework library I'm building to help bootstrap [IoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control), [O/RM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), etc., in an ASP.NET MVC application. I've written a simple build script for this framework library that looks like the following:

```
@echo off
echo.
echo Cleaning build output (removing 'obj' and 'bin' folders)...
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /b /ad /s bin') do rmdir /s /q "%%G"
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /b /ad /s obj') do rmdir /s /q "%%G"
rmdir /s /q build
echo.
echo Starting the build...
call "%VS100COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat"
msbuild Integration.build /target:Build
echo.
echo Done!
pause
```

This doesn't work. What I end up with in my `build` folder if I run this is, for whatever reason, assemblies that aren't fully rewritten by `ccrewrite` alongside `.pdb.original`, `.rewritten` and `.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt` files that litter the output directory.

What does work is first building the solution in Visual Studio 2010, commenting out line 3 through 7 in the batch file and running it again. I then end up with properly rewritten assemblies and no `.pdb.original` nor `.rewritten` files.

What I've deduced from this is that Visual Studio 2010 somehow triggers the Code Contract rewriter properly so the resulting assemblies from the Visual Studio 2010 build is re-used by the command-line MSBuild call, so what my batch script basically does is just copying files to the `build` directory. Rather useless, in other words.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209166/why-is-ccrewrite-exe-not-doing-anything-from-the-command-line), but Jon's problem seems different from mine since `ccrewrite` is obviously doing *something*, but it's just not completing the rewriting for whatever reason. The `Integration.build` file builds the correct configuration (that has Code Contracts enabled in the `.csproj` files) and everything else looks right, it just doesn't work properly.

So, I'm wondering: How do I run MSBuild the way Visual Studio 2010 is where `ccrewrite` does what it's supposed to and doesn't litter my output directory with `.rewritten` and `.pdb.original` files? Does anyone have a perfect example of how an MSBuild file doing proper Code Contracts rewriting looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the script. All Visual Studio is ever going to do is run MSBuild tasks that will invoke others. One thing you can do is go to Tools|Options|Build... and turn on logging so you can see in detail which bit is doing what to generate the artifacts.

How would one do such a complex and involved thing? Read [a guide to MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326445/is-there-a-good-tutorial-on-msbuild-scripts/1339390#1339390) such as [Hashimi p1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419659.aspx) and [Part 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd483291.aspx).

Then dig into the source for the build in e.g.:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets
```

The best way to get there is to open your .csproj and look what it includes and go via that (the .CSharp.targets is the first one - the one I cited comes further down the stack).

(That and wait for someone to pop in with an actual answer!)

Answer (score 1):

I've played a little with Code Contract's static analysis and it is pretty cool.
Now trying to set up TeamCity build ...

Here is [msbuild integration](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/userdoc.pdf) info from Microsoft Research (see page 44)