# How to use CodeContracts in C# 7.0?

Tags: c#

I have a simple question about Code Contracts in C#.

What is the main purpose of Code Contacts in C# ? So that I can use them in my application ?

Are they supported in .Net Core 3.0 any more ?

Is it considered to be old fashioned approach ?

Comment: This is too broad and opinon-based for SO - the first questions can be answered by an internet search and the last one is a matter of opinion.

Comment: Yeap, I was just wondering what was the best possible place for Code Contracts to be used in modern applications :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can find most of the information you are asking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42706669/how-to-properly-use-code-contracts-in-net-core) .
2. They are supported in Net Core (3.0 Preview 3 2.2 2.1 2.0 1.1
   1.0) and .Net Framework (4.8 4.7.2 4.7.1 4.7 4.6.2 4.6.1 4.6 4.5.2 4.5.1 4.5 4.0)'
3. As to whether it is old fashion, that is a matter of opinion. They are still used but with the popularity of automated testing not as much.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I guess u are right :) automated testing made Code Contracts be used less than previous years